# padding is different for 2 lists with the same amount of items with and same class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

I have created 2 lists and inserted items into them using JS. They both share the same class name, however when I set the padding, the list items have different results.
here is a fiddle with my code https://jsfiddle.net/ums1ptL9/1/

HTML

```
  <main>
    <section class="section" id="top">
        <h4>Contacts</h4>
    </section>

     <section class="section" id="mid">
         <ul id="contacts"></ul>
         <ul id="contactinfo"></ul>
    </section>

    <section class="section" id="bottom">
        <select id="dropdown">
            <option value="email">Email</option>
            <option value="number">Phone Number</option>
        </select>
    </section>
</main>
```

JS

```
   $('#contacts').append('<li class="itemname" id="'+i+'"><a href="#">' + contactarray[i].name + '</a></li>');
   $('#contactinfo').append('<li class="itemname">' + contactarray[i][$('#dropdown').val()] + '</li>');
```

CSS

```
  .itemname {
    padding: 11% 0 11% 0;
    border: 1px solid rgb(19, 19, 19);
}
```

please look at fiddle for full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percentages for `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` are based off the width of the containing block level element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top

So, since there is no equal explicit width set on contacts and contactInfo and the content in each list has a different natural width, the padding has a different computed value.

Comment: Because of this, you're better off using another relative unit like `em`. Something like `padding: 1em 0;` looks about right.

Comment: Agreed. Especially if both lists will have the same font-size.